# how to calculate CRC32 for 5-bit valid data using 8-bit parallel CRC calculator?

Tags: vhdl, crc32

I have an 8-bit parallel CRC32 calculator logic available in VHDL. I want to calculate CRC-32 over only **5 valid data bits**. How can I do that ?

Let's say "my_data" is : "01010"
But the problem is my CRC calculator would expect an 8-bit of data, so I tried to append 3-0's at the end of "my_data" so it would look like this : "01010_000". By doing this, I am getting a wrong CRC32 result.

Comment: What if you add the zeroes to the other end of your data?

Comment: so I tried to append 3-0's at the end of "my_data" so it would look like this : "01010_000". By doing this, I am getting a wrong CRC32 result.

Comment: Yea, so try putting the zeroes *at the other end*

Comment: Find or generate a 5-bit parallel CRC32 'calculator'.

Comment: @scary_jeff still didn't work.

Comment: @scary_jeff. Hey, it worked like you said when putting 0's at the front of the data. BUT, it again did not work for a 12-bit parallel CRC32 calculator. This time again my original data was 0xA and for making it a12-bit data I used 0x00A. It gave me wrong result.

Comment: I'd need to know more about the CRC-32. What is the initial value of the CRC register? In which direction are the bits rotated? What is the polynomial? What is the final exclusive-or applied to the CRC?

Comment: @MarkAdler Initial Value : All 1's

Comment: Still don't know enough.

Comment: @MarkAdler Initial Value: All 1's, Polynomial: 0x04C11DB7, First Serial: LSB. Actually, I generated the code from this http://www.sigmatone.com/utilities/crc_generator/crc_generator.htm

Answer (score 1):

Put your five bits in the most significant of the 8-bits you will feed to your logic, making the least significant three bits all zeros. Exclusive-or the result with `0x996495a3`. Done.

You need to put your five bits in the most significant bits of the byte, because your CRC starts with the least significant bit. Feeding a constant set of bits before your five bits only changes the result by an exclusive-or with some constant. (We could have made the low three bits anything, so long as they are always the same. Then only the constant we exclusive-or the result with would change.)

You can get the `0x996495a3` by exclusive-oring the CRC of five zero bits with the CRC of eight zero bits.

This C routine computes the standard CRC-32 (the one you're using, with a final exclusive-or with all 1's) of any number of zero bits:

```
uint32_t crc32zeros(unsigned zeros) {
    uint32_t crc = ~0;
    while (zeros--)
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xedb88320 : crc >> 1;
    return ~crc;
}
```

Then:

```
crc32zeros(5) ^ crc32zeros(8) == 0x996495a3
```

That final inversion doesn't change the constant you get, since the two inversions cancel. I included it just so that the result is consistent with a commonly used (probably the most commonly used) CRC-32.

An alternative with more calculations, but that permits any starting value of the CRC, would be to undo the effect of a few zeros at the end. In this case leave the five bits in the least significant bits, zeros in the upper three bits, compute the CRC with that byte and any starting value, and then undo the effect of the last three zeros. This routine in C does that:

```
uint32_t crc32unzeros(uint32_t crc, unsigned bits) {
    crc = ~crc;
    while (bits--)
        crc = crc & 0x80000000 ? ((crc ^ 0xedb88320) << 1) | 1 : crc << 1;
    return ~crc;
}
```

Then we have as an example:

```
crc32unzeros(crc32zeros(8), 3) == crc32zeros(5)
```

Comment: This works only when the CRC is initialized with All-1s. Suppose, in the first clock cycle I got 8-valid bits and in the next clock cycle I got 5-valid bits then this procedure fails. Because the result of 8-valid bit CRC is now fed to the design instead of all-1s.

Comment: I am having a little trouble in understanding the updated answer. I mean, how do I undo the zeros effect? Let's say my data is binary "10101010_10101" so I'd feed my 8-bit parallel CRC generator with data "10101010" and init_crc All-1s. Then, the result is fed as the crc_init along with new data "10101" to the CRC generator. Now how should I do it, in order to get the valid result?

Comment: Feed `10101010`. Then feed `00010101`. (Do not mess with the CRC between those.) You now have the CRC of `0001010110101010`, which is `0x78eca277`. Then undo the effect of the last three zeroes to get the CRC of `1010110101010`, which is `0x1c430639`.

Comment: >> Then undo the effect of the last three zeroes << How do I do it? Is it the same, 0x78eca277 ^ crc32zeros(16) ^ crc32zeros(13) ??

Comment: Thanks, Mark. The problem is I am trying to implement this in VHDL. It is actually the CRC32 implementation for 10G Ethernet. My data is of 8-bytes and I am using 8-byte parallel CRC generator for it. I am using the parallel CRC generator from sigmatone.com/utilities/crc_generator/crc_generator.htm  . Can you suggest me some better way to implement CRC32 for packets sizes which are not a multiple of 8-bytes. I am not sure how to implement CRC32unzeros() logic in VHDL. I want to calculate my CRC in one clock cycle which is the reason why I am using a parallel CRC generator.

Comment: The CRC was invented as a means to generate a check value on a stream of bits of any length (not just multiples of eight) with very little hardware, back when you would get four entire nand gates in one chip! As a result, a bit-wise CRC can be implemented with a tiny amount of resources of a modern gate array. All you need in this case is a 16-bit shift register and a few exclusive-or gates. You set the register to the initial value, feed the bits into the shift register in a serial fashion, and then read the CRC out of the shift register, possibly with a final exclusive-or.

Comment: I can't generate my CRC in serial fashion, which is the reason I am using a parallel CRC generator (for my clock speed requirement). 8-byte requirement came from my parallel data bus to support 10Gbps data requirement.

Comment: Then you'll need more tables. Is it always three bits more than a multiple of eight, or can it be any number of bits?

Comment: It would always be a multiple of 8-bits. So, for a 64-bit wide data bus (in my case) there can be 8/16/24/32/40/48/56/64 possible valid data bits.

Comment: What? Then why are you asking how to compute the CRC over five bits?

Comment: I asked it just for the simplicity. I thought it would be better to consider 8-bytes as 8-bits and if I am able to calculate any no. of valid bits among those 8-bit data then I would be able to resolve the 8-bytes case as well.

Comment: It actually worked for me when the initial values were all-1s. I tried to generate the CRC-32 over 6-bytes of valid data on an 8-bytes data bus, which gave me correct result. The problem came only when the CRC is not initialized to all-1s.

Comment: Can you please tell me what the logic, **crc32unzeros()** is doing? in terms of CRC32 calculation.

Comment: @Tushar It is simply reversing the operation of applying zero bits to the CRC. If you look at applying one zero: `crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xedb88320 : crc >> 1` , you will see that there are two paths depending on the conditional. The trick is to realize that which path was taken is encoded in the high bit of the result. If the high bit is 1, then the first path, exclusive-oring with `0xedb88320` must have been taken. If it is 0, then the second path must have been taken. That allows you to reverse the operation on each path.

Comment: I got your point in **crc32zeros** function. This is simply calculating crc32 on number of zeros. I couldn't understand the next function you mention as **crc32unzeros()** where you cancel the effect of zeros in crc32 calculation. Can you please tell me how do you cancel the effect of zeros?

Comment: That's what I just answered. Read my comment carefully.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't use a simple n-bit parallel CRC calculator logic to calculate a CRC over m-bits in parallel. It might work in some special cases depending on polynomial, data set, initial value, etc. So like @user1155120 already mentioned you need a 5-bit parallel CRC32 calculator for your case.

In case you need to calculate parallel CRC over different bit width a common solution is to implement one n-bit parallel CRC calculator block for every bit width you need to calculate and multiplex the calculator block outputs to the CRC register depending on your bit valid/enable signal.

Comment: Thanks @DirkH. But that would consume a lot of resources in the FPGA. I was thinking to save some.